# Page doesn't load properly on webbrowser vb.net

Tags: windows, vb.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer

i'm creating an application using vb.net to collect reviews from AliExpress. The thing is, when I load this page in the webbrowser, it loads all buttons and pictures, but buttons do not work, nothing works.

https://feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm?productId=32804434631&ownerMemberId=206096294&companyId=218486349&memberType=seller&startValidDate=&i18n=true

I already tried enable/disable javascript from IE, but it didn't work.

Something interesting, if i open this link from Chrome, everything works fine, but if I open the link from IE or from my app (webbrowser), loads everything but its not functional.

I'm pretty sure is some configuration with the IE but I haven't found anything yet in my research.

Any clue what's going on here?

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: „Collect“ is an euphemism for „stealing“?

Comment: No, it is not. It's more an import/export thing.

Comment: I don't think it's a configuration problem. Configuration rarely affects the functionality of standard webpages (unless you've disabled Javascript, of course). If it doesn't work in IE then it's most likely not compatible with it (it doesn't work in my IE browser either, by the way).